# ffmpeg audio conversion distorted - half rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an asf audio to mp3 using ffmpeg. 
But I have one specific audio that gets distorted in the middle and starts like if the person was talking in slow motion (at half rate).

The command I'm using is:

ffmpeg - i input.asf -ac 2 output.mp3

I've tried a lot of options, but about the middle of the audio is when it fails. 
The raw file sounds good, so it's not the recording. It is af in the middle of the transmission the frame rate went down for some reason.

Thanks all!

[EDIT]

I'm adding the console response after running the command as a suggestion from LordNeckbeard:

```
[root@mynasserver home]# ffmpeg -i recording-8532-1.asf -ac 2 -ab 64k -ar 44100 recording-8532-ac2-ar44100.mp3
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 29 2012 23:56:18 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --shlibdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[flv @ 0x86a4850]max_analyze_duration reached
[flv @ 0x86a4850]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'recording-8532-1.asf':
Metadata:
source          : STW MediaProxy v3.3.7.19894
Duration: 04:00:08.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, 2 channels (FC), s16
Output #0, mp3, to 'recording-8532-ac2-ar44100.mp3':
Metadata:
TSSE            : Lavf52.64.2
Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
size=  150906kB time=19315.93 bitrate=  64.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:150906kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000021%
```

So from the data above, you can see the input file is about 4hrs. The output ends up being around 5 hrs 20 mins.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the sample rate? Like -ar 44100.

Comment: Please provide the complete ffmpeg console output that results from your command.

Comment: @ BlueVoodoo - Yes, I've tried adding the -ar 44100 as well as -ab 64k, -ab 32k with same results.

Comment: `FFmpeg version 0.6.5` is considered old for general users. Please remove `-ac 2 -ab 64k -ar 44100` and try a [recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds). You may be experiencing a bug that may have already been fixed. If it also does not work please update your command and the complete console output.

Answer (score 0):

Using a current version of ffmpeg fixed this issue for me.

Do note that your "asf" file is actually an FLV file.

```
Input #0, flv, from 'recording-8532-1.asf':
```

Also, if the MP3 format isn't actually a requirement, you can just extract the AAC audio from the FLV file like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -acodec copy output.aac
```

This will preserve the audio quality.